# What's the difference between the Creative SDK and the Aviary SDK?

Tags: android, ios, asp.net-web-api, aviary, adobecreativesdk

I'm confused as to the difference between the Adobe Creative SDK and the Aviary SDK? Which one is better?

The Aviary signup is closed, so I can't download the Aviary SDK.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

See the [Aviary docs](https://developers.aviary.com/docs/android):

> **The Aviary SDK is now part of the Adobe Creative SDK**
>
> The Aviary SDK is
>   now the Image Editing component in the Adobe Creative SDK. Visit
>   CreativeSDK.com to access the latest Image Editing SDK and brand new
>   SDK components by Adobe, offering features like store to Creative
>   Cloud and publish to Behance.

Basically, the Creative SDK is an SDK that includes the Aviary SDK, and more. So the difference would be that the Creative SDK offers things that the Aviary SDK doesn't (and probably unrelated to it)

> which one is better

There is no 'better' pick

Answer (score 1):

At this point, the Creative SDK is the way to go. As noted on the old [Aviary developer site](https://developers.aviary.com/signup), new Aviary developer signups are no longer being accepted.

[The Adobe Creative SDK is available here](https://creativesdk.adobe.com/).